# Purchase domain name via API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Currently you can purchase a domain name on Azure via the UX.
Is there a way to purchase a domain programmatically via an API?
Need to develop a program / application / script that would purchase a domain among other tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can buy domain by rest api. You can read the offical doc about this.

Step 1. [Check Availability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/domains/checkavailability)

Step 2. [Create Or Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/domains/createorupdate)

Step 3. ...

[image]